# retrieve Datatype from property in c#?

Tags: c#, properties, model

I want to retrieve datatype of property inside a model(class) dynamically. thus UserInfo is a model class having many properties,

```
 List<FilterList> searchUserInfo = new List<FilterList>();
 UserInfo obj = new UserInfo();
 foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
 {
     searchUserInfo.Add(new FilterList { Filter = prop.PropertyType.DeclaringType.ToString(), FilterFor = "STRING" });
 }
```

// output is  System.String

but i want output  only string or int or bool without full url like System.Something.Something.int etc.
i want output like only: string, int, boolean. etc.

```
public class FilterList
{
    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public string FilterFor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Kosch actually this is not a duplicate question, Because in  you given link property attributes are accessed. but my question is how to get exact data type. like string, or int or bool..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
prop.PropertyType.DeclaringType.ToString()
```

To

```
prop.PropertyType.Name
```